# Image is downloaded in .bin format and also not in the download directory

Tags: android

I have created a context menu for downloading any image by long clicking the image, but the problem is that the file is downloaded in .bin format and also it not there in downloads folder. Please help!!!

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo)    //not learned
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view,contextMenuInfo);
    final WebView.HitTestResult webViewHitTestResult = webView.getHitTestResult();
    if(webViewHitTestResult.getType()==WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE ||  webViewHitTestResult.getType()==WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE)
    {
       contextMenu.add(0 ,1, 0, "Save - Download Image").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
       {
           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuitem) {
               String DownloadImageUrl= webViewHitTestResult.getExtra();
               if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(DownloadImageUrl))
               {


                   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadImageUrl));
                   request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                   request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                   DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                   downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Downloading...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
               else
               {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry.. Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
```

Comment: What is .bin format? What format should it be?  And if not in download folder then where? Has this something to do with a WebView?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what is .bin format, in download manager it is showing like (downloadfile.bin), it should be in .jpg or .png format. And it should be downloaded in download directory.

Comment: `Has this something to do with a WebView?`

Comment: `Sorry but i don't know what is .bin format, ` Those are your words. So how can you say that you dont know what is .bin format?

Comment: How does `DownloadImageUrl` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code

```
  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,    //Download folder
                                    URLUtil.guessFileName(DownloadImageURL, null, null));  //Name of file

                            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```